# Multiple possible values for variable in shell

Tags: bash, shell

Is there some way to assign one value out of some possible values in shell like this :

```
variable = $(command1) or $(command2)
```

Knowing that only one of these two commands gives a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The || operator will evaluate command2 if command1 returns a non-zero (error) return code.

```
variable=$(command1 || command2)
```

Similarly, the && operator will evaluate command2 if command1 returns a (ok) zero return code.

```
variable=$(command1 && command2)
```

e.g. Assignment of variable:

```
var=$(ls zasdasd || echo "file does not exist") 
echo $var    ## outputs "file does not exist"
```

Error output can be suppressed by directing error stream 2 to `/dev/null`

```
var=$(ls zasdasd || echo "file does not exist") 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
variable=$(command1 2>/dev/null || command2 2>/dev/null)
```

This will assign output of `command1` to `variable` if it is successful otherwise it will assign output from `command2`.

`2>/dev/null` is there to suppress stderr in case any of the commands fail.